# C# Multiple Rows of Textboxes manipulation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a WPF with SQL db to keep track of my orders.

I have 5 TextBoxes * 10 rows (50 in total)
Product Items (named as pur_Items1 to 10)
Price (named as pur_Price1 to 10)
Discount (named as pur_Discount1 to 10)
ShippingCost (named as pur_Shipping1 to 10) and
Total Item Cost (named as pur_Total1 to 10)

What is the best practice to don't write 60 lines of the following ugly looking code?

```
double i1 = Convert.ToDouble(pur_Items1.Text);
double p1 = Convert.ToDouble(pur_Price1.Text);
double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(pur_Discount1.Text);
double s1 = Convert.ToDouble(pur_Shipping1.Text);
double t1 = Math.Round(((i1 * p1) - d1) + s1,2);
pur_Total1.Text = Convert.ToString(t1.Text);
```

I have few ways but failed miserably

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a [Grid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Sorry I'm new in WPF & C#.
Do you mean DataGrid?
If yes i don't know how to manipulate the rows/columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `DataGrid` to display dynamic tabular data.

Here's an example:

XAML:

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <DataGrid Name="dg"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    dg.ItemsSource = Products;
  }

  readonly ObservableCollection<Product> Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

  private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  {
    foreach(var product in Products)
    {
      //Save product to database
    }
    Products.Clear();
  }

public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  string _Item;
  public string Item
  {
    get => _Item;
    set
    {
      _Item = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
  }


  decimal _Price;
  public decimal Price
  {
    get => _Price;
    set
    {
      _Price = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
      RaiseCostChanged();
    }
  }

  decimal _Discount;
  public decimal Discount
  {
    get => _Discount;
    set
    {
      _Discount = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
      RaiseCostChanged();
    }
  }

  decimal _ShippingCost;
  public decimal ShippingCost
  {
    get => _ShippingCost;
    set
    {
      _ShippingCost = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
      RaiseCostChanged();
    }
  }

  public decimal Cost => Price + ShippingCost - Discount;


  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null) =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  protected void RaiseCostChanged() => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Cost));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but i don't want to display database entries but to import them into my mssql. I don't understand how this can be used. 
What i already have can be seen here http://prntscr.com/gp38jd
Top is date of purchase, Vendor, order id, quantity of items (was planning to dynamically create rows but failed on that too.

Comment: Cool! This seems to be as i wanted it.
The followup-question is how can i get each row to the sql query?
What i used before to fill the Vendors table is this 
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products] " +
                                    "([Id],[OrderId], [ProductName], [Quantity], [Price], [Discount]," +
                                    " [TotalCost], [City], [Country], [Active]) " +
                                    "VALUES(" + ?? + ", N'" + ?? + "', N'" + ?? +
                                    "', N'" + ?? + ")";

Comment: 1) Please post as separate question, showing what you've already tried. 2) If this question helped you, please upvote and/or accept as answer.

Comment: @MoDuL see the `foreach` loop I added to the answer.

Comment: So now each column's row will be as Product.Item (which will mean row0,cell0 = Item?) If yes i can work with that..
I've tried multiple way since last night my head is spinning :)

Comment: Not quite. `Products` is a collection of `Product` elements. In my code, each product has a `string` field that stores a single `Item` value. If you want each product to hold multiple `Item`s, that's called a Master Detail scenario. [Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)'s a good example on how to implement this. Just replace the detail UI with a list of items.